# How to call button tap functionality outside of button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call the onTap functionality outside of my button. As soon as I receive my OTP, I want to call the onTap of my manually created widget. I have a custom widget called as `LoginCTA` and I want to call it's onTap after I receive my OTP in `initSmsListener` method which I called in `initState`.

My code -

```
String _comingSms = 'Unknown';

  Future<void> initSmsListener() async {
    String comingSms;
    try {
      comingSms = await AltSmsAutofill().listenForSms??"";
    } on PlatformException {
      comingSms = 'Failed to get Sms.';
    }

    if(!mounted)
      return;

    setState(() {
      _comingSms=comingSms;
      print("\n \n \n Coming SMS - $_comingSms");
      otpController.text = _comingSms[23] + _comingSms[24] + _comingSms[25] + _comingSms[26]
          + _comingSms[27] + _comingSms[28];
    });
    //Apply here -
    
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    initSmsListener();
    super.initState();
  }

isOTP
                      ? LoginCTA(
                          //After input otp
                          onPressed: () async {
                            print(Provider.of<APIData>(context, listen: false)
                                .loggedIN);

                            if (emailEntered &&
                                otpController.text.length == 6) {
                              bool res;
                              try {
                                res = await widget.signInWithOTP(
                                    contactController.text, otpController.text);
                              } catch (e) {
                                res = false;
                                print(e);
                              }

                              if (res) {
                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                  msg: "Verifying OTP...",
                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                                  textColor: cardColor,
                                  backgroundColor: primaryTextColor,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                );
                                Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                                  print(Provider.of<APIData>(context,
                                          listen: false)
                                      .loggedIN);

                                  if (Provider.of<APIData>(context,
                                              listen: false)
                                          .loggedIN ==
                                      1) {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          btnText: otpButtonText,
                          isDisabled: isDisabled,
                        )
                      : LoginCTA(
                          //After input mobile number
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (emailEntered &&
                                contactController.text.length == 10) {
                              widget.sendOTP(contactController.text);
                              setState(() {
                                isOTP = true;
                                isDisabled = true;
                              });
                            } else {
                              print('kuch na kuch glti');
                            }
                          },
                          btnText: buttonText,
                          isDisabled: isDisabled,
                          hasIcon: hasIcon,
                        ),
```

Comment: what about inkwell and gesturedetector widget .which wrap other widget and provide ontap and etc click event

Comment: Create function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the functionality out into its own function. Then you can assign the function to `onTap` and also call it whenever you like.